# python multiprocessing self-feeding consumer locks forever

Tags: python, process, queue, multiprocessing

The problem is that the consumer never exits, it just hangs doing nothing. The code was intended to work like this:

A queue is created and some task_data passed into it. A specified number of consumers are created to process the data. When a consumer finds out that the queue is empty, because there is still a chance that another consumer could put something into the queue, it cannot leave, however it can indicate in the `consumers_finished` list that it has no jobs. The consumers loop goes on until every worker indicates that they finished the work. It is not known how much work there will be, because the consumers put tasks into the queue. I read something about this but it was not clear whether processes can hang on waiting forever if they feed themselves.

```
class Consumer(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, task_queue, results, consumers_finished):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.task_queue = task_queue
        self.results = results
        self.consumers_finished = consumers_finished

    def run(self):
        while not all(flag for flag in self.consumers_finished.values()):
            task_data = self.task_queue.get()
            if not task_data:
                self.consumers_finished[self.name] = True
                continue

            self.consumers_finished[self.name] = False
            task_result = self.do_some_processing(task_data)
            self.task_queue.put(task_result)


class Starter(object):

    def start(self):
        manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
        task_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
        results = manager.list()
        consumers_finished = manager.dict()

        consumers = [Consumer(task_queue, results, consumers_finished) for i in range(self.consumers_count)]

        for consumer in consumers:
            consumers_finished[consumer.name] = False
            consumer.start()

        task_queue.put(task_data)

        for consumer in consumers: consumer.join()

        return results
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19071529/python-multiprocessing-125-list-never-finishes

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a good sleep really helps, a refreshed mind can do much more..
Anyway, I found a solution after studying the python documentation.

```
class Consumer(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, task_queue, results, consumers_finished):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.task_queue = task_queue
        self.results = results
        self.consumers_finished = consumers_finished

    def run(self):
        while not all(flag for flag in self.consumers_finished.values()):
            try:
                task = self.todo_queue.get(False)
                self.consumers_finished[self.name] = False
            except QueueEmpty:
                self.consumers_stopped[self.name] = True
                continue

            task_result = self.do_some_processing(task_data)
            self.task_queue.put(task_result)


class Starter(object):

    def start(self):
        manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
        task_queue = manager.Queue()
        results = manager.list()
        consumers_finished = manager.dict()

        consumers = [Consumer(task_queue, results, consumers_finished) for i in range(self.consumers_count)]

        for consumer in consumers:
            consumers_finished[consumer.name] = False
            consumer.start()

        task_queue.put(task_data)

        for consumer in consumers: consumer.join()

        return results
```

This is a part from the python documentation, which explains my problem I think:

> Warning As mentioned above, if a child process has put items on a
>   queue (and it has not used JoinableQueue.cancel_join_thread()), then
>   that process will not terminate until all buffered items have been
>   flushed to the pipe. This means that if you try joining that process
>   you may get a deadlock unless you are sure that all items which have
>   been put on the queue have been consumed. Similarly, if the child
>   process is non-daemonic then the parent process may hang on exit when
>   it tries to join all its non-daemonic children. **Note that a queue
>   created using a manager does not have this issue.** See Programming
>   guidelines.

So I just changed the queue, it is now created by the manager, and in the consumer's run method tasks are taken from the queue in a different way, see the code.