# Python multiprocessing >= 125 list never finishes

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to implement this multiprocessing [tutorial](http://toastdriven.com/blog/2008/nov/11/brief-introduction-multiprocessing/) for my own purposes. At first I thought it did not scale well, but when I made a reproducible example I found that if the list of items goes above 124, it seems to never return an answer. At `x = 124` it runs in .4 seconds, but when I set it to `x = 125` it never finishes. I am running Python 2.7 on Windows 7.

```
from multiprocessing import Lock, Process, Queue, current_process
import time

class Testclass(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

def toyfunction(testclass):
    testclass.product = testclass.x * testclass.x
    return testclass


def worker(work_queue, done_queue):
    try:
        for testclass in iter(work_queue.get, 'STOP'):
            print(testclass.counter)
            newtestclass = toyfunction(testclass)
            done_queue.put(newtestclass)

    except:
        print('error')

    return True

def main(x):

    counter = 1

    database = []
    while counter <= x:
        database.append(Testclass(10))
        counter += 1
        print(counter)



    workers = 8
    work_queue = Queue()
    done_queue = Queue()
    processes = []

    start = time.clock()
    counter = 1

    for testclass in database:
        testclass.counter = counter
        work_queue.put(testclass)
        counter += 1
        print(counter)


    print('items loaded')
    for w in range(workers):
        p = Process(target=worker, args=(work_queue, done_queue))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)
        work_queue.put('STOP')

    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    done_queue.put('STOP')

    newdatabase = []
    for testclass in iter(done_queue.get, 'STOP'):
        newdatabase.append(testclass)

    print(time.clock()-start)
    print("Done")
    return(newdatabase)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    database = main(124)
    database2 = main(125)
```

Comment: he posted another question here that worked for me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19070638/python-multiprocessing-ioerror-errno-232-the-pipe-is-being-closed#comment28188856_19070638

Comment: I fixed the problem in the other post. I've tried running the code above on both of my computers and on both it hangs at the end when `x=125` and never prints Done.

Comment: At 125 it doesn't stop for me either.  Python 2.7.5 on Windows Vista.  It's seemingly waiting forever to `.join()` one of the processes.  Suggest you try to whittle it down to a minimal failing case, then [open a bug report](http://bugs.python.org/).  Also fails to terminate under Python 3.3.2.

Comment: Interestingly, this fails to stop even if `workers` is set to 1.  It **appears** that the processes don't stop "because" `done_queue` hasn't been drained.  If I change `worker()` to do `done_queue.put('STOP')` at the end, and change `main` to take that line away, instead invoking `done_queue.get()` until `'STOP'` has been seen `workers` times, then this code works fine even for a million items.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK!  From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html):

> Warning As mentioned above, if a child process has put items on a queue (and it has not
>   used JoinableQueue.cancel_join_thread), then that process will not terminate until all
>   buffered items have been flushed to the pipe.
>   This means that if you try joining that process you may get a deadlock unless you are sure
>   that all items which have been put on the queue have been consumed. Similarly, if the
>   child process is non-daemonic then the parent process may hang on exit when it tries
>   to join all its non-daemonic children.  Note that a queue created using a manager does
>   not have this issue. See Programming guidelines.

As I noted in a comment earlier, the code attempts to `.join()` processes **before** the `done_queue` Queue is drained - and that after changing the code in a funky way to be sure `done_queue` was drained before `.join()`'ing, the code worked fine for a million items.

So this is a case of pilot error, although quite obscure.  As to why behavior depends on the number passed to `main(x)`, it's unpredictable:  it depends on how buffering is done internally.  Such fun ;-)

Comment: Do you recommend any particular work around for the code above? Is there another way that people usually get the finished product back from the queue?

Comment: I already explained in a comment how I "fixed" this:  Change `worker()` to do `done_queue.put('STOP')` right before it ends.  Change the main program's iteration over `done_queue` to count the number of times it sees `'STOP'` - it's done when it sees `workers` of them.  Move the `.join()`s **after** the iteration over `done_queue` is finished.